# How to select the last 7 rows in column in Excel 2013?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

I have googled the answsers. But all i find is "select last row OR column" but not "select last N rows or columns".

How can I select the last 7 rows in a column in Excel 2013?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. This one uses `Offset` and `Resize`.

```
Sub SelectLast7()

    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim Last7Rows As Range

    LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set Last7Rows = Range("A" & LastRow).Offset(-6, 0).Resize(7, 1)
    Last7Rows.Select

End Sub
```

`LastRow` is the last row in the column from below. `Offset(-6,0)` gets the cell 6 offsets *above* `LastRow`. `Resize(7,1)` resizes your target cell by 7 rows and 1 column (basically, you just adjust the row). `Select` finishes it out.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer, but is there a formula solution?

Comment: Do you mean a formula solution to *select and highlight* the last 7 rows?

Comment: to refer the last 7 rows in sheet A and display it in sheet B，A & B are in the same .xlsx file